# summary object refactoring

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have a summary objects, who's responsibilities actually to combine a lot of things together and create a summary report, who later going to be serialized into the XML.
In this objects I have a lot of structures like this:

```
public class SummaryVisit : Visit, IMappable
{
    public int SummaryId { get; set; }

    public int PatientId { get; set; }

    public int LocationId { get; set; }

    public IMappable Patient
    {
        get
        {
            return new SummaryPatient(PatientBusinessService.FindPatient(this.PatientId));
        }
    }

    public IMappable Location
    {
        get
        {
            return new SummaryLocation(LocationBusinessService.FindLocation(this.LocationId));
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<IMappable> Comments
    {
        get
        {
            return new SummaryComments(CommentBusinessService.FindComments(this.SummaryId, Location));
        }
    }

    // ... can be a lot of these structures
    // ... using different business services and summary objects

    public IEnumerable<IMappable> Tasks
    {
        get
        {
            return new SummaryTasks(TaskBusinessService.FindTasks(this));
        }
    }
}
```

PatientBusinessService, LocationBusinessService etc. are statics.
And each of these SummaryPatient, SummaryLocation etc. have the same type of structure inside.

What is the best approach to refactor and unit test this?

Tried to replace static calls with calls via the interfaced proxies (or refactor statics to non-static classes & interfaces), but this class just got a lot of these interfaces as the constructor injection stuff and start to be super greedy. In addition, these interfaces have a one used method inside (if I going to create it just to this summary needs).

And as soon as this is a summary object, commonly this static services used just once for the whole structure to get appropriate properties for output.

Comment: This might be a better question for [codereview.se]. If you move it there, I may comment that you might want to refactor the `IMapper` properties to methods, to make it clear that they are for the purpose of calling "static services used just once for the whole structure to get appropriate properties for output". Also, resist the urge to use static services, ever, and just use instance services. If that offends, you then only ever create one instance of the service, but you can tell NInject to do that for you.

Comment: That's a legacy code - trying to refactor it and make better. :)

IMapper - minimum interface, to treat property value for serialization (we have custom one here). As soon as methods can't be 'serialized' - that's not an option. Statics are bad - I know. Trying to replace it with wrappers here or refactor static by himself as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your tests to be more integrational (test more than one class at the time).  You could try to modify your services to be more universal and be able to take data from different sources (like TestDataProvider and your current data provider).

Better solution I think is to modify classes you want to test:

1. Use strong typing for properties and gain all benefits. I think you should return more specific types instead of *IMappable*
2. It looks like some of your data is stored inside class (ids) some data is not (IMappable object references). I would refactor this to hold references to objects inside class:

   ```
   private SummaryPatient _patient;
   public SummaryPatient Patient
   {
       get
       {
           if (_patient == null)
               _patient  = new SummaryPatient(PatientBusinessService.FindPatient(this.PatientId));
           return _patient;
       }
   }
   ```

Then you can assign your tests data in constructor or create static method `CreateDummy(...)` just for unit tests. This method then should use `CreateDummy` for child objects. You can use it in your unit tests.

Comment: Commonly I use moq to emulate interface of service cals to DAL factories.

Comment: And as soon as this particular object combines a lot of data, setup and maintain this huge fake data set can be problematic. And what type of test set I need to provide to be sure all data from DAL placed on the appropriate places in this big final object structure?

Comment: To your question: I don't think testing your `Summary` class should involve DA layer. Maybe you should consider implementing some kind of backdoor for creating `Summary` class with appropriate child objects? See my answer update.

Comment: hmm... faking properties, not services - new idea I need to consider - thanks.

Also trying to create one kind of proxy/factory layer for all this static calls and make couples inside something like

    `class ProxyLayer
    {
        public IMapper GetSummaryPatient(patientID)
        {
            return new SummaryPatient(GetSummaryPatient(PatientBusinessService.FindPatient, patientId));
        }
    
        protected PatientEntity GetSummaryPatient(Func<int, PatientEntity> patientGetter, int patientId)
        {
            return patientGetter(patientId);
        }
    }`

Comment: Pawel, and you think it's not really necessary to test `new SummaryPatient(PatientBusinessService.FindPatient(this.PatientId));` logic at all?

Comment: I wish I knew. Maybe it is enough to do this kind of testing separately from `SummaryVisit`. For example in `SummaryPatient` as standalone test. But still it will test many layers at the same time. I`ve seen in big projects that in your situation common practice was to do integrational tests only (with database connection to a test database) - Many layers tested at the same time.

Comment: In some projects I've seen architecture that each high level object (your `SummaryVisit`) contained reference to `Data` object for lower layer actions (like `SummaryVisitData`). This object was responsible for DA calls and data caching. In this case it is easier to replace `Data` object for unit testing.